# opening a parent folder and highlighting particular child in default file browser using python

Tags: python, directory, nautilus

I am using following code to open a folder in default file browser.

```
if os.name == 'mac':
  subprocess.call(('open', folderPath))
elif os.name == 'nt':
  subprocess.call(('start', folderPath))
elif os.name == 'posix':
  subprocess.call(('xdg-open', folderPath))
```

Now the problem is I want to highlight the child folder/file which was selected earlier. Is there any way to do it? If not for all, at least for nautilus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) doesn't support this, so it has to be done on a per-app basis. After poking around the [Nautilus code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/tree/src/nautilus-main.c#n340), I don't think it has this feature either. So, yeah, you're pretty much out of luck.

For Windows Explorer, you can use

```
subprocess.call(("explorer", "/select,", file_path))
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, After searching a lot I feel the same :(